# Jquery UI checkbox as button change text value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, button, checkbox

I am using Jquery UI and currently trying to change the text on the Checkboxes (they look like buttons). For some reason I am unable to get the text to change on each change event using the toggle method. Here is what the html is coming out like this in IE 8

```
    <div data-hands-jqui-type='buttonset' data-hands-jqui-props='{"buttonWidth":0,"disabled":false,"handsOnCreate":null}' class='editor-field ui-widget'>
        <label for="IsClosedSunday">Open</label>
        <input data-hands-jqui-props="{}" data-hands-jqui-type="checkfield" data-hands-onchange="Vendor.IsClosedSelected" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Open field is required." id="IsClosedSunday" name="IsClosedSunday" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="IsClosedSunday" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </div>
```

To me it looks like the label is what i need to change, but I couldn't figure out how to get to it.

Now i found on another So thread to use this:

```
  $("#IsClosedSunday").button().toggle(function () {

        $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Open');
    },
        function () {
            $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Closed');

        });
```

With this set up, I get it to change from 'Open' to 'Closed' when checked, but it doesn't go back to 'Open' on uncheck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DYCpD/)

```
   $("#IsClosedSunday").button().click(function () {
    var text = $(this).is(':checked')? "Closed": "Open"
        $(this).button('option', 'label', text);
    });
```

You can use `change` event too.

```
$("#IsClosedSunday").button().change(function () {
    var text = $(this).is(':checked')? "Closed": "Open"
        $(this).button('option', 'label', text);
    });
```

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

In your code you are using `toggle()` it is not an event on the button(rather checkbox). It just forces the toggle state for the button when you call `.toggle()` initially. it wont get triggered when you check or change the checkbox. you should to use `change` or `click` event for that. Also i think toggle doesn't support 2 call backs.

Comment: Thank you so much. i had seen something similar to this but wanted to use the toggle. we actually are using an onchange event, it is just using custom widgets we are using "data-hands-onchange="Vendor.IsClosedSelected". I think what the issue was is what you said about the toggle only running first time. That is exactly what was happening... Thanks again sir!!